# Rails 4 dynamic form nested attributes without hidden input

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hiddenfield

Previously I asked a question about building an attendance list getting the students and building a check list to mark attendance and came up with this.

```
def new
    @attendance_list = @classroom.attendance_lists.new

    @attendance_list.attendances = @classroom.student_ids.map do |student_id|
      @attendance_list.attendances.build(student_id: student_id)
    end
end

def create
    @attendance_list = @classroom.attendance_lists.new(attendance_list_params)
    @attendance_list.classroom_id = params[:classroom_id]

    respond_to do |format|

end
```

params

```
params.require(:attendance_list)
  .permit(:post_date, :remark, 
          attendances_attributes: [:student_id, :attended, :remarks ])
```

with simple fields

```
= simple_form_for [@school, @classroom, @attendance_list] do |f|
  = f.input :post_date
  = f.input :remark

    = f.simple_fields_for :attendances do |g|
      ** you see i needed a hidden student_id **
      = g.input :student_id, as: :hidden
      ......
```

model

```
class AttendanceList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :classroom
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :students, :through => :attendances

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attendances
end

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :attendance_list
end

class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
  has_many :attendance_lists

  validates :class_name, presence: true
end
```

how do I do without the hidden input because this line doesn't seem to work.

```
build(student_id: student_id)
```

Comment: paste model and form

Comment: Hi I added it to the question

Comment: in student model have you defined association for attendance_lists?

Answer (score 0):

```
class AttendanceList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :classroom
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :students, :through => :attendances
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attendances
end

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :attendance_list
end

class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
  has_many :attendance_lists

  validates :class_name, presence: true
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :attendance_lists, :through => :attendances
end
```

view file

```
= simple_form_for @student do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :attendances do |g|
      ** your code **
```

Comment: The `simple_form_for` is using `attendance_list` so do you mean `simple_fields`? And thanks for spotting that for me! Must have missed that `has_many :attendance_lists, :through => :attendances`

Comment: It doesn't work because i think the parent of attendance is attendance_sheet.